# When 'business' means 'company,' is it a countable noun?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

This is from [The Washington Post article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/opinions/1990/04/29/hello-mr-chips-pcs-learn-english/6487ce8a-18df-4bb8-b53f-62840585e49d/) :

> What's a company to do? In today's litigious and document-deluged
> workplace, a poorly written manual can lead to liability suits and
> even low-risk decisions are justified by streams of memos. One
> solution is training, and American **business** is already spending
> more on education than all the U.S. public school systems combined.
> But increasingly organizations are turning to another solution --
> software. The next few years will see a flood of computer programs
> that either help writers improve what they've written, or do much of
> the writing for them.

I think, in this context, the plural form 'businesses' should be used because I consider '**business**' to mean 'company.'

Am I wrong?

Comment: The cited usage is *by definition* "uncountable", since it uses the ***singular*** form. But It would be perfectly valid to use the same word as a "countable" noun meaning (a) ***company.*** In which case it would have to be the plural form *...American **businesses are** already spending more on education...*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you very much.

Comment: "American business" reads as "The american business sector as a whole" in the above sentence.    If the author chose to say "american busineses", it would have been a very similar overall sentence, but you are not the author so you can't say which the author meant to say.

Comment: The answer to the question title is ‘Yes’ — but that's not really what the question body is asking, which has a different answer…

Comment: @WarrenP Thank you very much.

Comment: @gidds Thank you very much.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In this context "business" doesn't mean "company". It means "private commercial operations in America, considered collectively" (defn adapted from Wiktionary).  In this sense it is *uncountable*. It means "the business sector" of American society, in contrast to the education, health, or government sectors.

It would be possible to rephrase since "American business" is composed of many businesses.  In the same way as "American education" is composed of many schools.

Comment: And yet we often talk of small businesses, family businesses, local businesses. Are we Canadians really alone in doing so on this side of the Atlantic?

Comment: Yes, of course.  "Business" can also be a countable noun, meaning a company.  But in the example it doesn't mean "company".  It is an uncountable sense of the word.

Comment: Every American business is part of American business.

Comment: @JamesK Oh, right. I didn't actually finish reading the example, just your answer. Foolish me!